# NetSuite Eliminate Duplicates from Saved Item Search

Tags: search, netsuite

I am making a saved search to show all of the items in our inventory with quantity details, but when I preview the saved search many duplicate products are displayed to the screen. How can I eliminate the duplicates? Also, how would I eliminate any Kit/Package items?

Comment: Are you using multiple locations feature? Also, what are your search columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is likely you have multiple location inventory turned on but are not filtering by nor including a column for the Inventory Location. If you include the Inventory Location column you'll see that the lines are not duplicates.

If you don't have inventory in a number of locations you can filter on Location On Hand is greater than 0. The filters to use here depend on what you are trying to see.

You would eliminate Kits/Packages by filtering on Type == Inventory Part

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I'm really new to NetSuite, my manager just kind of threw me into this project without knowing much about how to use it!

Answer (score 1):

To eliminate only Kits/Package items from search results you can use filter criteria - Type none of Kits/Package Item.

If you are using multiple locations and you do not want to see multiple results for same item - I would recommend writing a grouped/summary search by specifying summary types for fields in the results/search columns:

1) All Item details like  - Name, display name , etc. with summary type as group

2) All inventory count field such as Location on Hand, Location Available, Location Back Ordered, etc. should have summary type as Sum